# How to make install using path with space and dot

Tags: macos, makefile, configure

I want to make install(`sudo make install`) using path with space and dot. (e.g. `/Applications/Sample App.app/Contents/Resources`)

However, following error invoked.

`ginstall: target 'App.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libserialport.a' is not a directory`

If I use the path with only space, `sudo make install` really works well with `\` escape character.

Comment: Did you write the makefile yourself? Could you post it somewhere?

Comment: No, I'm trying to build `libserialport` library(https://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport). I followed the build guide shown as in their website, `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`

Comment: The following is prefix part of `Makefile`

Comment: `prefix = /Applications/Sample\\ App.app/Contents/Resource`

Answer (score 1):

Makefiles and pathnames which contain spaces do not mix well.  Make uses whitespace to split strings into lists.  For example, of you write this:

```
SOURCES = foo.c bar.c baz.c
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(SOURCES))

program: $(OBJECTS)
```

Then make will treat the variables `SOURCES` and `OBJECTS` as *lists* of strings, split on whitespace characters, and `program` will depend on the three items `foo.o`, `bar.o`, `baz.o`.

Make does not know at all that some strings should not be split this way (because they refer to pathnames).  Like many early scripting languages, it is completely based on string interpolation.  This is true for the shell script fragments used to write the build steps as well.

There are some workarounds possible, but they all depend on how variables are used within the makefile.  Recursive makefiles can pose additional problems if the contents of these variables are passed down explicitly to the invoked make command using the shell.

In some cases, the fix is rather simple, so if there is an install rule like this:

```
install: program
    $(INSTALL) -m 755 program $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/program
```

It may be sufficient to add quotes, like this:

```
install: program
    $(INSTALL) -m 755 program "$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/program"
```

But this really depends on the makefile in question.

If the project uses automake (like `libserialport`), the simplest solution is to use the `DESTDIR` support in the generated makefile to install the whole thing to a path which does not contain spaces, and then move it to the final destination afterwards.  This assumes that the project does not internally embed the final installation path, though.

Comment: I used the `DESTDIR` you said like `sudo make install DESTDIR=/usr/local`, but installation directory was set to `DESTDIR/prefix`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you rephrase? Is `DESTDIR/prefix` an actual directory, or a placeholder?

Comment: I mean `DESTDIR` + `prefix` directory, but I want to install into `DESTDIR` directory apart from `prefix`

Comment: Simply, I just want to install `libserialport` library with `/Applications/Sample App.app/Contents/Resource` prefix, because my `C++` application refers to exactly that directory.

Comment: Ah. You need to revert your `prefix` edit in the makefile, so that it's again `/usr/local`. And you probably should not use `DESTDIR=/usr/local`, but something like `DESTDIR=/tmp/libserialport-build`. Then you can copy the built library from the `/tmp/libserialport-build` directory.

Comment: However in that way, my `C++` application will refer to the directory which to I don't want. Because, my `C++` application should be built with `libserialport`.